# What is the song's name of One Piece cap 717 min 15:02

Tags: one-piece, music

I have been looking for the name of the song that appear in 15:02 on episode 717 when Kyros and Rebeca were reunited after the fight versus Diamante.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New World One Piece ost - the time of promise (dressrosa)
That's what i have found